# Random File Access Java

Tags: java, image

I know there's a way to select a random file from a directory, but I don't know how it's coded in Java. I have pseudocode though. What I'm asking is if I could get a nudge in the right direction. My pseudocode is as follows:

```
dir = "directory";
String[] files = dir.listfiles();
String next = rand.nextInt(files.length);
Image img = next;
```

The reason I want to do it like this is because I have a *long* list of images that I would like to shuffle through.

Comment: Are there only files (no other directories) in the directory?

Comment: What's wrong with the pseudocode you have above? Looks like it should work, besides the fact that `listFiles` returns an array of `File` objects and not `String`s

Comment: @peeskillet: There are a couple of other directories, but I don't care if they are/aren't included. Also, I'm not worried about the psuedocode being incorrect, I just don't quite know how to put it into Java-code.

Answer (score 4):

Your pseudo code looks fine, you can get all the names recursively, store the names in an ArrayList, and randomly retrieve the names from the ArrayList as shown below:

```
static ArrayList<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    File dir = new File(".");
    getFileNames(dir);
    Random rand = new Random();
    String next = files.get(rand.nextInt(files.size()));
}

private static void getFileNames(File curDir) {
    File[] filesList = curDir.listFiles();
    for (File f : filesList) {
        if (f.isDirectory())
            getFileNames(f);
        if (f.isFile()) {
            files.add(f.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be on the right track. Only thing is `listFiles()` returns a `File[]` not a `String[]`

Maybe try something like this

```
File file = new File(filename);
File[] files = new File[0];     // initialize
if (file.isDirectory()){
    files = file.listFiles();   // populate
}
int fileIndex = new Random().nextInt(files.length);      // get random index
Image img = new ImageIcon(files[fileIndex]).getImage();  // create image
```

Though the above may work, It's recommended using URL for embedded resources and not Files. Something like this

```
String[] filenames = file.list();    // list returns String
int fileIndex = new Random().nextInt(filenames.length); 
Image img = null;
java.net.URL url = MyClass.class.getResource(filenames[fileIndex]);
if (url != null){
    img = new ImageIcon(url).getImage();
} else {
    img = null;
}
```

When using the `class.gerResource()`. The file will be searched for in the location of the class files. You can can also change the path a little bit, for example if you want a file structure like this

```
ProjectRoot
          bin
             MyClass.class
             images
                  image1.png
                  image2.png
          src
```

Then you can use this code

```
java.net.URL url = MyClass.class.getResource("images/" + filenames[fileIndex]);
```

Comment: Is filename the name of the directory containing the images?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would implement your pseudo-code

```
private static final Random random = new Random(0x20131224 ^ // A seed value
      System.currentTimeMillis());                           // and more seed value(s).
public static File getRandomFile(String filePath) {
  File f = new File(filePath);                               // Do we have a directory?
  if (f == null || ! f.isDirectory()) {
    return f;
  }
  File[] files = f.listFiles();
  List<File> al = new ArrayList<File>();
  for (File file : files) {
    if (file != null && file.isFile() && file.canRead()) {   // Make sure it's a file.
      al.add(file);
    }
  }
  return al.get(random.nextInt(al.size()));                  // Get a random file.
}
```

Comment: There's no need to add a seed value to the Random, unless you want the same values each time... The default no-args constructor does the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
File filedir=new File("C:\\Users\\ramaraju\\Desktop\\japan02-12\\");
File[] files=filedir.listFiles();

Random generator = new Random();
int Low = 0;
int High = files.length;
int R = generator.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;
System.out.println(R);
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    if(i==R)
    {
        System.out.println(files[i].getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow (SO)! It's always good to check the formatting before submitting the post. It's right under the text box. Also, it's always good to have some text accompanying your post. You can edit it to include some more information.